# Yii - something wrong with if & else if statement in view file

Tags: php, if-statement, yii

I'm having a problem with else if statement in my view file.

I'm using Yii framework and I have the following code in my view file.

```
<select class="formRightPulldown" name="Post[password]">    
<?php foreach($passwordData as $password) :?>

<option value="<?php echo $password['id'] ?>" 
    <?php if(isset($updateErrorPost) && 
             $updateErrorPost['password']==$password['id']){
             echo 'selected';  
          } else if(isset($postUpdate) && 
             $postUpdate['password']==$password['id']){
             echo 'selected'; } ?>
 >
     <?php echo $password['name'] ?>
 </option>

<?php endforeach ;?>
</select>
```

I believe when "$updateErrorPost" is set to be true, it shouldn't read the code after "else if".

But somehow, even when "$updateErrorPost" is set to be true, it reads the code after "else if", so that "selected" value is added to multiple option tags.

Does anyone knows what's causing this problem?

Am I misunderstanding something very basic in php programming???

Please give me a help!

Thanks in advance :)

***+++Added+++***

It ends up adding selected value to multiple option tags like the below...

```
<select class="formRightPulldown" name="Post[password]">
    <option value="3">temporary</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Subscriber</option>
    <option value="1" selected>VIP</option>
</select>
```

In the code above, the first selected value is added when the first if-statement is true, and the second selected value is added when the else-if-statement is true.

Why although if-statement is true, code after else-if is read???

Comment: what error you are facing

Comment: If `$updateErrorPost` is set to `true` the `if` will fail on the password check

Comment: Thank you for comments!! I add more detail on my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<select class="formRightPulldown" name="Post[password]">    
<?php foreach($passwordData as $password) :?>

<option value="<?php echo $password['id'] ?>" 
    <?php if(isset($updateErrorPost) &&  ($updateErrorPost['password']==$password['id'])) {
             echo 'selected';  
          } else if(isset($postUpdate) && ($postUpdate['password']==$password['id'])) {
             echo 'selected';
        } 
    ?>>
     <?php echo $password['name'] ?>
 </option>

<?php endforeach ;?>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh!!!! Thank you very much!! It worked!

So, what I need was to surround A==B with ().
I learned :)

Thanks again!

Comment: While this works, it's like reinventing wheel. Yii [has dropdown list](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail) for "freehand" use or [bound with form](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#dropDownList-detail) (which in fact is same, it's just for consistency).

Answer (score 0):

> I believe when "$updateErrorPost" is set to be true, it shouldn't read the code after "else if".

Not necessarily - since you have `&& $updateErrorPost['password']==$password['id']` there, then `} else if {...` will be run if `$updateErrorPost['password'] != $password['id']`

Try to make 2 seperated `if { }` without `else` having complete set of conditions and see if it works - this will help you find out where you have logic error.

Comment: ahh, actually, "$updateErrorPost['password']==$password['id']" is true  as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
foreach($passwordData as $password) {
    $selected = "";
    if((isset($updateErrorPost) && $updateErrorPost['password']==$password['id']) ||
        (isset($postUpdate) && $postUpdate['password']==$password['id'])
    ){
        $selected = "selected";
    }
    echo "<option value='{$password['id']}' {$selected}>";
    echo $password['name'];
    echo "</option>";
}
```

Also make sure `$updateErrorPost` and `$postUpdate` arrays has `['password']` key every time. Otherwise you should do `isset()` by array key. e.g. `isset($updateErrorPost['password'])` and another one too.

**Updated:**  If you want to echo exactly `selected` word when any of 2 conditions equals `true`, It should be correct.

Comment: >make sure $updateErrorPost and $postUpdate arrays has ['password'] key every time

Yes, I just made sure that both have 'password'key.

Comment: @Hayato Did you try my suggested code? Is your problem still there?

Comment: Im sorry that I guess i didn't give enough info.

the code I showed on my post is actually within "foreach".

<?php foreach($passwordData as $password) :?>

Therefore, I can't try your code as it is.

Comment: But I tried "||" instead of "else if" as you suggested. But it still read the code before "||" and the code after "||", although both returns true boolean.

Comment: @Hayato If you want to echo exactly `selected` when any of 2 conditions equals to true, It should be OK.